# This PLY is too dark! How to improve it?

Tags: import, vertex-colors

Please, how to improve darkness in this PLY: http://156.54.99.175/3d/sodark.zip  ? It is too dark! What's the issue?

Comment: shouldn't this be merged with this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38577/this-ply-is-too-dark-how-to-improve-it  -- it's the same problem, but OP isn't using Cycles..

Comment: @zeffii I think you have posted the comment in the wrong question

Comment: I don't care which is merged into which, but chronologically -- perhaps the other question should merge into this one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is not a Blender-related issue: the vertex colors are the ones the file provide.

Here's what they look like in [Meshlab](http://sourceforge.net/projects/meshlab/):

[image]

And in Blender:

[image]

put apart the different viewport shading by seeing the true solid colours in cycles preview or textured mode in blender render, and you'll see no difference:

[image]

[image]

---

You can **tweak** the vertex colors with nodes as liked:

[image]

Note that vertex colors are changed only in the viewport, for rendering purpose, not in the vertex color layer. If you want to store a new, brighter, vertex layer you should:

- bake cycles tweaked vertex color to an image texture
- convert the texture to a new vertex color layer

Comment: so, no other way to set up colors?

Comment: What are the steps to brighten the colors? Can you be more specific?

Comment: The step to brighten the color is just one: add a RGB Curve node (or a Brightness&Contrast node, or ecc...) and tweak its parameters (ex. last picture). Is this what it was not clear?

Comment: You can also use vertex paint mode, but I don't think you'll easily get a good result. This is the way I know, but maybe someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Thanks @Carlo, your answer is appreciated. How I can add a RGB Curve node in Blender? Step by step... if you can.

Comment: Wow that's great! Thankyou! And how to apply corrections exporting the model in PLY format agarin?

Comment: You must somehow bake the new colors in a vertex layer. If you are using Cycles you'll have to unwrap and use a texture as stated at the end of the answer, but it is easier to work with Blender Internal for this task. You can find the instructions at the end of this asnwer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38640/15140.